# How to code more efficient to avoid "Apex CPU time limit exceeded"?

Tags: apex

I have a Web Service class. When I call the method from this class, I get "Apex CPU time limit exceeded" error. The `for` loops are causing this trouble. Here's my not efficient code:

```
List<Task> tasks = [SELECT Id, WhoId FROM Task];
List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id FROM Contact];

for (Task t : tasks){
    for(Contact c : contacts){
        if (t.WhoId == c.Id){
            //some logic here   
        } 
    }
}
```

This piece of code matches the related `Task` and `Contact` objects. How to make it more efficient? Is there a way to reduce the number of loops here to one?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a Map instead:

```
List<Task> tasks = [SELECT Id ... FROM Task];
Map<Id, Contact> contacts = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT Id ... FROM Contact]);

for (Task t : tasks){
    Contact c = contacts.get(t.WhoId);
    if(c != null) {
        //some logic here   
    }
}
```

This technique was originally used to avoid script limits, and it's equally effective to avoid timeout limits.

### Edit

As stated by Mike, you should make sure your filters are also correctly limiting records to avoid heap limits and query limits, and your field list should include only the fields necessary to complete the task.

```
Task[] tasks = [SELECT Id ... FROM Task WHERE ...];
Map<Id, Contact> contacts = new Map<Id, Contact>();
for(Task record: tasks) {
    if(record.WhoId != null && record.WhoId.getSObjectType() == Contact.SObjectType) {
        contacts.put(record.WhoId, null);
    }
}
contacts.putAll([SELECT Id ... FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contacts.keySet()]);
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem stems from your SOQL queries; they're fetching ALL Tasks and ALL Contacts. Here's one way to improve that:

1. Filter your tasks to only those relevant
2. Retrieve those WhoId that belong to Contacts by checking their prefix
3. Fetch the necessary Contacts

   ```
   List<Task> tasks = [SELECT Id, WhoId FROM Task WHERE /* INSERT FILTER */];
   List<id> taskWhoId = new List<id>();
   for (Task t : tasks){
     // Only take those matched to a Contact
     if (t.WhoId.startsWith('003'){
       taskWhoId.add(t.WhoId);
     } 
   }

   Map<Id,Contact> contacts = new Map<id, Contact>([SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE ID in :taskWhoId]);    
   for (Task t : tasks){
     if contacts.containsKey(t.WhoId){
       Contact taskContact = contacts.get(t.WhoId);
       // Do something with the Task and Contact
     }
   }
   ```

As Phil points out, you could also combine this into one query, if you can filter on Contacts instead of Tasks (that depends on your requirements).

Comment: Actually, the queries aren't the topic of this question-- they're asking about eliminating the inner loop. That aside, some notes: (1) you didn't check if t.whoId is null first, so NPE if there is no contact, and (2) you really should use `t.WhoId.getSObjectType() == Contact.SobjectType` instead of checking the key prefix, since, in theory, the key *could* change and this code would no longer operate as expected (I know it "shouldn't", but as an external developer, one cannot guarantee that).

Comment: Both are good points. I plain forgot the first problem and never considered using getSObjectType in my comparisons before; I'll star using that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

My crack at it:

```
List<Task> tasks = [SELECT Id, WhoId FROM Task];
map<id,Contact> contactMap = new map<id,Contact>([SELECT Id FROM Contact]);

for (Task t : tasks){
    Contact thisTasksContact = contactMap.get(t.whoId);
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: A bit more information about your solution would be great.

Comment: which part?  the map construction?  or why the map?