# Update of records failed using Workbench if it is more 5K records.. Throwing error like CPU timeout

Tags: workbench

When I am using work bench for udpdating 40K records(Contacts) getting error even it is running in anonymous batch..throwing error like ..CPU time out. :(

Comment: Hi Uday, your question will likely be better answered if you update it to add some details. For instance: how you are updating those records through workbench and what is the exact error message you are receiving.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to to this [POST](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22223/how-to-code-more-efficient-to-avoid-apex-cpu-time-limit-exceeded) if you were not able to resolve this yet.

And I would suggest to go through this [article on new Script Limit introduced in Winter'14](http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2013/09/script-limits-begone.html) as well.

Thanks