# Getting "Apex CPU time limit exceeded error" for a function

Tags: error

I am getting the following error:

> Class.COBM.generate_update_sql: line 425, column 1 Class.COBM.:
>   line 326, column 1 Trigger.ProcessingCodeAfterTrigger: line 77, column
>   1 11:22:29:944 (48457879190) |FATAL ERROR|System.LimitException: Apex
>   CPU time limit exceeded

May I know the cause of this error and what can be done to solve it?

Comment: [avoid Apex CPU time limit exceeded](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232681&language=en_US&type=1)

Answer (score 1):

Your customization is way to heavy. E.g. you have too many collections, for loops etc.

Add profiling to your [logs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_debugging_debug_log.htm) - it will help you to find problem places.

```
CODE_UNIT_STARTED [EXTERNAL]||AccountTrigger on Account trigger event BeforeUpdate
...
LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS (default)|
LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS   Maximum CPU time: 185 out of 126000
LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS   Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
```

Each function that you are using, will be presented in logs. In my example AccountTrigger uses 185 ms.

After you identify problem place - you might optimize it. 
Or you can execute your code asynchronously - where limits should be higger comparing to syncronous execution.

Comment: How can we execute the code asynchronously?

Comment: Batch apex. What have you added to your code recently? You might not using collections properly. E.g. [example](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22223/how-to-code-more-efficient-to-avoid-apex-cpu-time-limit-exceeded)

Comment: Except that adding profiling to your logs will *increase* your CPU usage...